# Removing duplicate addresses with unique person names

Tags: excel, duplicates, formulas

I have duplicate addresses with different names in each row of Excel. I have about 17,000 entries that I need to clean up. Here is an example:

```
    Name        Address             City                    Zip
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1   Al a Moe    7009 Plainfield     Dearborn Heights MI     48127
2   Al a Adel   7009 Plainfield     Dearborn Heights MI     48127
3   Al a Amy    7009 Plainfield     Dearborn Heights MI     48127
4   Al a Ashly  7009 Plainfield     Dearborn Heights MI     48127
```

How do I delete the rows with the duplicate addresses, without mixing up the database of names and addresses and only keeping one address per name?

I need a formula that can fix it to only one row with one address and one name

Thanks.

Comment: You don't have any duplicates there. Can you show what you expect the data to look like after you're done?

Comment: Does it matter which name is chosen for the de-duplicated addresses?

Comment: I am hoping to have just one name and one address. It does not matter which name as long as there is one address. All four of the examples to just one row.

Comment: Hello Tim, I was curious if you had any luck with this?

Answer (score 0):

String together the address components in a 'helper column' (Address&City&Zip) then apply Remove Duplicates to that column (only). Apply Remove Duplicates to the Name column only and delete the helper column.