# Removing duplicate addresses with unique person names 3rd time I ask

Tags: excel, duplicates, excel-formula

This is the 3rd time I ask only because I really need done asap. I have duplicate addresses with different names in each row of Excel. I have about 17,000 entries that I need to clean up. Here is an example:

```
    Name        Address             City                    Zip
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1   Al a Moe    7009 Plainfield     Dearborn Heights MI     48127
2   Al a Adel   7009 Plainfield     Dearborn Heights MI     48127
3   Al a Amy    7009 Plainfield     Dearborn Heights MI     48127
4   Al a Ashly  7009 Plainfield     Dearborn Heights MI     48127
```

How do I delete the rows with the duplicate addresses, without mixing up the database of names and addresses and only keeping one address per name?

I need a formula that can fix it to only one row with one address and one name

Thanks.
Bass

Comment: Data >> Remove duplicates.

Comment: is there any reason to post it twice? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22203857/removing-duplicate-addresses-with-unique-person-names

Comment: I am just trying to get this done as fast as possible. It being a new question might attract news eyes who have not seen the first post.

Comment: Tim, the data tab to remove duplicates does not work the way you think it will with my particular problem. When I do that it mixes up all the names and addresses. I need a formula to keep all the rows in order and delete the rows with the same addresses.

Comment: -1 stop posting the same question and answer the comments on the first question you asked.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make a copy of your data.
2. Delete the name column from one of them.
3. Use the Excel remove duplicates function to get only one row per address.
4. Add a column and do a lookup to the copy of your original dataset to get a name.  If you need a specific value like MAX etc.  try something like =MAX(IF($A$1:$A$5="A1",$B$1:$B$5))  You may need to create a column that concatenates the entire address into one field for a proper lookup for example if the same address exists in multiple cities/states etc.

This should give you one name and one address per row without any duplicate addresses.

If you can load this data into a SQL database this would be considerably easier.

```
SELECT MAX(Name), Address, City, Zip FROM Addresses
GROUP BY Address, City, Zip
```

---

A few modifications specific to your data set.

1. I transformed all of the address data to upper case as excel comparisons are case sensitive and some of your dupes were the same but with case differences.
2. I moved the address column to be the first column when doing the lookup.
3. Slightly different VLOOKUP parameters as your names were in different columns so I had to do one lookup for each.

Comment: I tried it and its not working. Is it possible to show you the address database so you can get an understanding of it?

Comment: Sure thing.  I'm just not quite sure how you would show me.  If its in a database and not excel I can write you a SQL statement to do it all in one shot.  Can maybe write a VBA function to do it in excel.  Let me know and will see what I can do to get this solved for you.  :-)

Comment: its in excel. Is there is a way I can get it to you?

Comment: Upload to dropbox or somewhere I can get to it on the web or a mockup with similar data if your data is protected. Post the link here and I'll take a look.  Thanks.

Comment: please let me know when you get it

Comment: Got it.  Looking now.

Comment: if you notice there are a lot of duplicates. I hope this isn't too difficult.

Comment: That's awesome, you did it so quickly.

Comment: Did you use the same formula that you gave me earlier?

Comment: No.  I used a regular VLOOKUP.

Comment: If you look in the first two columns of the "Processing" sheet you will see the function.  :-)